# Storage/File delete methods don't delete the file from storage

Tags: laravel

I am uploading images to `storage/uploads` and have a queue job that uploads those images to AWS. Here is the code of the job:

```
$path = storage_path() . '/uploads/' . $this->fileId;
$fileName = $this->fileId . '.png';

if (Storage::disk('s3images')->put('profile/' . $fileName, fopen($path, 'r+'))) {
   File::delete($path);
}
```

Once the image has been uploaded to AWS the job is supposed to delete the image from `storage/uploads` but it's not doing that. The images are successfully uploaded to AWS. I tried to delete specific files directly without the if-statement but nothing seems to work. I even tried with `Storage::delete` but that didn't work either. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
Storage::delete('upload/profile/' . $fileName);
```

[See Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#deleting-files)

Comment: The `s3images` is the AWS bucket, I don't want to delete files from it. I want to delete files from `storage/uploads` instead.

Comment: Could you add `config/filesystems.php`?

Answer (score 0):

If your specifying the full directory path of the file you can use unlink a native way to delete files from the server.

```
$path = storage_path() . '/uploads/' . $this->fileId;  
$fileName = $this->fileId . '.png';
$isUploaded = Storage::disk('s3images')->put('profile/' . $fileName, fopen($path, 'r+'));

if ($isUploaded) {
  unlink($path);
}
```

Documentation: [unlink php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)